# bool to System.Windows.Visibility (binding issues when dynamically creating DataGridColumnHeaders)

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, datagrid, visibility

I am caught up in a scenario where I have to dynamically create datagrid columns and must create the columns in C# code. I have a checkbox in a separate area of code for each generated column. The checkbox determines whether or not the specific column is hidden or visible. The checkbox is bound to the GameAttributes.Visible property. However, the DataGrid Visibility property is of a different type. I tried using the BooleanToVisibilityConverter, but still receive a compile error (as I figured).
Does any have any efficient workarounds to this problem?

The error I am encountering:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Windows.Visibility'
```

**EDIT:** Compiler error has been resolved, however the binding does not appear to work for visibility.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
              DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Name="GameDataGrid" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              CanUserAddRows="False" 
              CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              >
```

View:

```
GameAttributes.Add(new GameInfoAttributeViewModel() { Visible = true, Description = "Name", BindingName = "Name" });
GameAttributes.Add(new GameInfoAttributeViewModel() { Visible = false, Description = "Description", BindingName = "Description" });
GameAttributes.Add(new GameInfoAttributeViewModel() { Visible = false, Description = "Game Exists", BindingName = "GameExists" });
foreach (GameInfoAttributeViewModel attribute in GameAttributes)
{

    DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn
    {
        Header = attribute.Description,
        Binding = new Binding(attribute.BindingName),
    };

    Binding visibilityBinding = new Binding();
    visibilityBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Visible");
    visibilityBinding.Source = attribute;
    visibilityBinding.Converter = new BooleanToVisibilityConverter();
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(column, VisibilityProperty, visibilityBinding);

    GameDataGrid.Columns.Add(column);

}
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace DonsHyperspinListGenerator
{
    class GameInfoAttribute
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool Visible { get; set; }
        public string BindingName { get; set; }
    }

    //todo: move to separate class
    class GameInfoAttributeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private GameInfoAttribute mGameInfo = new GameInfoAttribute();

        public string Description
        {
            get { return mGameInfo.Description; }
            set
            {
                if (mGameInfo.Description != value)
                {
                    mGameInfo.Description = value;
                    InvokePropertyChanged("Description");
                }
            }
        }

        public bool Visible
        {
            get { return mGameInfo.Visible; }
            set
            {
                if (mGameInfo.Visible != value)
                {
                    mGameInfo.Visible = value;
                    InvokePropertyChanged("Visible");
                }
            }
        }

        public string BindingName
        {
            get { return mGameInfo.BindingName; }
            set
            {
                if (mGameInfo.BindingName != value)
                {
                    mGameInfo.BindingName = value;
                    InvokePropertyChanged("BindingName");
                }
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void InvokePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            PropertyChangedEventHandler changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed != null) changed(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't have anything to do with your binding or your value converter.  You're making this assignment:

```
Visibility = attribute.Visible
```

where you create a new column in the View.

That's your compile error.  Visibility is a System.Windows.Visibility, and attribute.Visible is a bool.  You can't set Visibility to a bool.  If this value is being set via a Binding anyway, then you really don't need to be setting it manually (indeed it will clear your Binding).

**Edit:**

Here's an example of how to set the binding in the code behind to use the value converter:

```
var binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = attribute;
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Visible");
binding.Converter = (BooleanToVisibilityConverter)Resources["BoolToVisibilityConverter"];

BindingOperations.SetBinding(column, DataGridTemplateColumn.VisibilityProperty, binding);
```

**Second Edit:**
I see a couple of things in the above code that may be a problem:

Firstly, when you're setting your binding, it looks like you're setting the binding on just "`VisibilityProperty`" for your DependencyProperty.  I'm not sure what that is in the context of your view (probably `UserControl.VisibilityProperty`, or something).  The specific DependencyProperty that you want to set is on the DataGridTemplateColumn type, so I believe you'll want to set it to `DataGridTemplateColumn.VisibilityProperty` instead.

So this line: `BindingOperations.SetBinding(column, VisibilityProperty, visibilityBinding);`

becomes this: `BindingOperations.SetBinding(column, DataGridTemplateColumn.VisibilityProperty, visibilityBinding);`

Another thing is this line in your object initializer for the DataGridTextColumn:

```
Binding = new Binding(attribute.BindingName),
```

I'm not sure what you're doing with that line, but it could possibly be causing an issue with the overall DataContext of the column (which may in turn cause a problem for the Visibility binding).  I'm not positive that it's an issue, but it's definitely *not* needed for setting the Visibility Binding.  I had the code that I provided in my answer working in an example project, and all I added where the lines I provided above (after taking out the assignment in the column initializer that had caused the compile error.

Comment: I've always known why and where the error is coming from. The problem is to ensure it updates the checkbox is toggled. I do agree though, the visibility setting is redundant, however it does not resolve the problem.

Comment: It wasn't clear in your question that you know the reason for the compile error.  I think what you'll need to do is manually set the binding in the code behind.  Given that your column is a dynamic object that you're creating in the code behind, you can also set the binding in the code behind.  I've updated my answer to give an example of that.

Comment: That makes much more sense to me now. Thanks jdmcnair. I am a step closer, but still have a little further to go. For some reason it appears that the visibility binding does not take effect. Based on my edited code above, only the first column should be visible, however they are all visible, regardless of when I change the Visible property. My guess is that I am blatantly forgetting something.

Comment: See response in "Second Edit" in the above answer.

Comment: You are a binding god! I needed to set DataGridTextColumn.VisibilityProperty instead. This has been quite a learning experience. Thanks!